# MYSQL-Update Existing Varchar column GUID values to Binary

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MYSQL database with GUID(or UUID) stored as Varchar(36). To improve performance, I want to convert them to Binary(16). For new values I can use something like

> INSERT INTO sometable (SOMECOLUMN,UUID) VALUES
>   ("Something",UNHEX([the-uuid]))

But how can I update the existing stored GUID values to Binary(16)?

Comment: If the hex encoding of a value is up to 36 characters in length, then the value is up to 18 bytes wide—not 16.  Perhaps you meant to say they're currently `VARCHAR(32)` instead of `VARCHAR(36)`?

Answer (score 6):

Got the answer myself.

In case anyone else need it. Here it is

**Change the Type of GUID column to VARBINARY to avoid right padding.**

> ALTER TABLE `newtable` MODIFY COLUMN `id` VARBINARY(36) NOT NULL;

**Update the existing id data to the BINARY id**

> UPDATE newtable set id=UNHEX(REPLACE(id,'-',''));

**Now change the column datatype to BINARY(16)**

> ALTER TABLE `newtable` MODIFY COLUMN `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL;

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE sometable ADD newColumn BINARY(16) AFTER UUID;
   ```
2. Update the table:

   ```
   UPDATE sometable SET newColumn = UNHEX(UUID);
   ```
3. Drop the old column and rename the new one (if so desired—often best *not* to rename, so that application code that has not been updated will fail rather than use the table incorrectly):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE sometable DROP UUID, CHANGE newColumn UUID BINARY(16);
   ```

Comment: Foreign keys will not allow to use the new column.

Comment: @user4259788: Well, obviously, you will need to adjust your foreign keys accordingly...

Comment: Thanks for you help, I got the answer myself and posted it already.